# Shifting using week. in SAS

Tags: sas

I wanted to shift the week calculation in SAS, this is my following code:

```
PUT(WEEK(DATEPART(t1.ORDER_DATE)), WEEK.2) AS WEEK
```

However, this calculation does not work, it still calculates week from Sunday to Saturday and I want it to calculate from Monday to Sunday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use INTNX, you can shift it however you need.

```
select INTNX('DTWEEK.2',order_date,0) format=DATETIME17. AS WEEK from test t1;
```

Then put it however you want to store the week value.  (I'm keeping it a DATETIME here, if you want to convert it ahead of time do so and remove the DT from DTWEEK.)